Funky behavior when calling System.out.println from virtual threads
When running an example program that calls the System.out.println method from java's new virtual threads, I am getting some weird results. Here's the sample program:
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class VirtualThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 200; i+=1) {
            Thread.ofVirtual().start(() -> {
                System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
                System.out.flush();
                expensiveTask();
            });
        }

        sleepMainThread();
    }

    private static void expensiveTask() {
        var bi = BigInteger.ONE;
        for(int i = 2; i < 50_000; i+=1) {
            bi = bi.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
    }

    private static void sleepMainThread() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60_000);
        } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}

At first the program will print the current time in increasing order, but after a while it will print values in the past, e.g.:
2024-05-08T14:17:34.925188363
2024-05-08T14:17:34.925920200
2024-05-08T14:17:34.925993640
2024-05-08T14:17:34.926365126
...
2024-05-08T14:17:50.927143298
2024-05-08T14:17:51.136285346
2024-05-08T14:17:34.925684196  // prints value in the past
2024-05-08T14:17:51.251390867
2024-05-08T14:17:51.309471812


Anyone know why this happens? Thanks.

System.out.println is buffered output, if you do not flush the buffer, output will not be sequential

It's not about buffering because all the threads use the same buffer. System.out.println uses a PrintStream and it is synchronized internally. The thread that prints out the old timestamp just waited for it's turn to print the timestamp it created longer than other threads. The order in which the threads get into the synchronized block is pretty much random.

I just tried with flush() but still the same. I'll add that to the code.

in short, the execution of one thread is not atomic, that is, it can be interrupted to allow another thread to run (in the posted code, for example interrupting exactly after calling now() and before calling println())

@Torben Oh i think i get it, it's some synchronized stuff that doesn't play well with virtual threads. I just found it weird that it doesn't happen with platform threads.

@user85421 there is no time-sharing when it comes to virtual threads

It's fundamentally the same with all kinds of threads, not just virtual ones. You have 200 threads competing for a lot fewer than 200 cores so most of the threads are bound to be forced to wait. anyway, fro mthe user manual: Virtual threads are suitable for running tasks that spend most of the time blocked, often waiting for I/O operations to complete. However, they aren't intended for long-running CPU-intensive operations. You're specifically using them in a way they were not intended to be used. :)

@user9532210 Oh, so you have 200 threads all running in parallel (not just concurrently)? Your results indicate otherwise....

@user85421 Virtual threads will not stop running at any point like typical OS threads, that's one difference

@user9532210 - can you share the documentation of that? I can't believe you would have 200 virtual Threads running in parallel, at one instance of time, on less CPU cores. Even the corresponding JEP states that the virtual Threads are run on a few OS threads, eventually even just on one - impossible to have 200 threads running at one instance on fewer OS threads.

@user85421 https://openjdk.org/jeps/425 "The scheduler does not currently implement time sharing for virtual threads."

@user9532210 I was writing to ask you to consult the Scheduling virtual threads section of JEP444, the grand-child of that one you posted. On the beginning of that section: "the JDK's scheduler assigns virtual threads to platform threads (...). The platform threads are then scheduled by the OS as usual." - now there are even to scheduling involved - the usual one and the Java one. And after the sentence you posted, at the end of that section is an explanation of time sharing. (not core sharing or cpu sharing or whatever that is called)

@user9532210 Again, impossible to have 200 threads running in parallel on lesser CPU cores and the results you got support that

Modifying your output stream to print the threadId might make the output much meaningful and relevant. System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().threadId() + " : " + java.time.LocalDateTime.now());. Sharing a sample output on my local machine ...534 : 2024-05-08T14:39:16.156736 451 : 2024-05-08T14:39:07.785228 535 : 2024-05-08T14:39:16.221775 536 : 2024-05-08T14:39:16.236423 537 : 2024-05-08T14:39:16.310685 538 : 2024-05-08T14:39:16.344265 539 : 2024-05-08T14:39:16.391551 540 : 2024-05-08T14:39:16.414124 541 : 2024-05-08T14:39:17.078302 456 : 2024-05-08T14:39:07.785313....

The only reason I could think of is that a "time-traveler" thread was suspended after it executed LocalDateTime.now() , but before it executed System.out.println. I surrounded the entire statement with lock.lock and lock.unlock where lock is declared as static final and assigned to = new ReentrantLock();  and now I don't see any "time-travellers". Could you check that?

If so the issue is not specific to virtual threads. Platform threads render to me the same behavior.

Just to state the obvious and to summarize the above discussion: the reason of out-of-order output is that the line
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());

is not atomic, as @user85421 correctly pointed out, and if one thread loses control after completion of LocalDateTime.now() and before completion of System.out.println this out-of-ordering may happen.
The remedy might be as simple as the enclosing both statements in a critical section:
private static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
...
lock.lock();
try {
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}

and the out-of-ordering is no more. Obviously, the issue is not specific to virtual threads whatsoever, the same behavior can be observed for platform threads as well. For them, good ole intrinsic/monitor lock, acquired by synchronized statement, might be as good as ReentrantLock.

Addendum: while loosing the CPU in-between is the most likely reason for out-of-order time stamps, especially with larger discrepancies, it doesn’t have to. When two or more threads acquire timestamps in parallel, followed by printing them parallel, out of order timestamps are always possible, even when no thread pauses in-between.

@Holger, very true! I am still on single-processor mindset :scream:. I'll edit  correspondingly

…and for completeness: when I replace Thread.ofVirtual() with Thread.ofPlatform() in the OP’s source code, I also see out of order timestamps on my machine, just not as big outliers as with virtual threads.

@Holger, yes, that what I meant when said "the same behavior can be observed for platform threads as well". Was reluctant to spoon-feed the audience (already did so) with exact method of creation platform threads.

Many virtual threads are started, but some virtual threads are not played immediately by real threads. You can see its time is later than the last virtual thread around that time, that was played okay.
It might be you are seeing starvation, where a later virtual thread gets a thread first. I suspect a relation with the number of actual physical threads that are available.
